# Boolean in Angular Service is not working as expected

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-services

Basically I have a Boolean `canSiteReload` in my service that's based on another Boolean `hasChanges` in the same service.

The service looks like this:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplicationService {

  constructor() { }

  public hasChanges: boolean = false;
  public canSiteReload: boolean = this.hasChanges === false;
}
```

The problem is, when I change `hasChanges` to true, `canSiteReload` will still return true, even though `this.hasChanges === false`should return `false` because `hasChanges` is now true.

Why is this happening and how can I make `canSiteReload`'s value based on `hasChanges`? If possible I want to avoid extra code e.g. no functions/setters.

Reproducer: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rwcza8

Comment: WIth your code, `canSiteReload` is initialised and then it's value is never modiffied. You need a method or a getter if you want canSiteReload to change when the other variable changes

Comment: as David said or you could simply use `!hasChanges` instead of `canSiteReload`

Comment: @David For some reason I thought `canSiteReload` would be evaluated everytime it is called, makes perfect sense if this is actually not the case. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As David said,`canSiteReload` is initialized but its value is never updated.

`canSiteReload` does not update, even when `hasChanges`'s Value was updated to `true`.

To fix, we need to add a getter for `canSiteReload`:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplicationService {

  constructor() { }

  public hasChanges: boolean = false;
  public get canSiteReload(): boolean{
    return !this.hasChanges
  }
}
```

`canSiteReload` is now evaluated everytime it is called.

Additional conditions can be added after `!this.hasChanges`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-z3uyqw

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @David's comment. Without writing function, `canSiteReload` doesn't seem to be updating.

I forked and changed following part:

```
this.appService.hasChanges = false;
```

I created a function in service, and updated value using that function. Like this:

```
public change(): void{
  this.appService.saveChanges(true);
  console.log('Has changes?: ', this.appService.hasChanges);
  console.log('Can site reload?: ', this.appService.canSiteReload);
}

public undo(): void{
  this.appService.saveChanges(false);
  console.log('Has changes?: ', this.appService.hasChanges);
  console.log('Can site reload?: ', this.appService.canSiteReload);
}
```

and it's working I think.

Forked: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aeyxgg

Answer (score 0):

The `canSiteReload` variable is defined once at the start of the `ApplicationService` and it is never updated again. There are multiple ways to achieve your requirement. Here is one method using Rxjs `BehaviorSubject`.

Application Service

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApplicationService {
  private hasChangesSource = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private hasChanges$ = this.hasChangesSource.asObservable();

  public canSiteReload: boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.hasChanges$.subscribe(status => this.canSiteReload = !status);
  }

  get hasChanges() {
    return this.hasChangesSource.value;
  }

  set hasChanges(status: boolean) {
    this.hasChangesSource.next(status);
  }
}
```

I've modified your [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jun3e8).